# tagManager2 - вывод карточки товара

Tags: modx

Использую tagManager2. Всё делал по инструкции [отсюда](http://bayguzin.ru/main/uroki/uroki-modx-revolution/tag-manager2.html). В итоге получаю такую вот [беду](http://bambizova.posh.pro/novyij-katalog?page=1).

Фильтр работает [3:43], но печатается массив вместо карточки товара.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массив печатается если не указан шаблон вывода.

Comment: да вы были правы, как раз в этом и была причина

Comment: @ДмитрийБережной, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).